# Postgres: pull column value into row header and value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 12.8. My table stores variables for a single process instance in this way:

[image]

I need to create single row per id so that the column name will be the variable name (for example: appealDto, offshoreOnly, dueDate etc)  and the value will be the variable value. So, it should look like:

```
id_                 |        offshoreOnly      |     dueDate
------------------------------------------------------------
ecb-sad-23132       |      0                    |16356454656
```

**Notice** that this table has an interesting way of storing variable value. It uses 1 of the 3 columns (double_, long_, text_) to store the variable-value depending on the variable's type.

I tried but best I could do:

```
select v.id_ proc_id , 
    (case when v.name_='dueDate' then v.long_ else null end) due_date,
    (case when v.name_='offShoreOnly' then v.long_ else null end) offShoreOnly
from camunda_data.act_ru_variable v
```

And that did not give me the expected result.

Also tried:

```
select v.proc_inst_id_::text , 
     v.name_::text,
    v.long_::text
from camunda_data.act_ru_variable v 
where v.proc_def_id_ NOT ILIKE 'StartProcess%'
and v.name_ in ('dueDate','offShoreOnly')
```

But that gave me :

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need :

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc SCHEMA camunda_data;
```

And the query that finally worked:

```
select * from crosstab (
$$select v.proc_inst_id_::text , 
     v.name_::text,
    v.long_::text
from camunda_data.act_ru_variable v 
where v.proc_def_id_ NOT ILIKE 'StartAppealProcess%'
and v.name_ in ('dueDate','offShoreOnly')$$)
as (proc_id text, due_date text, offshore text);
```